# ThreadStatic in asynchronous ASP.NET Web API

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, async-await, threadstatic, requestscope

Is there a possibility to use thread static like variables within a single request? The current code uses a thread static variable for logging purposes and now we want to use async controller methods (with async and await pattern) which results in problems because the variable is null when a new thread is opened.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`await` can cause thread jumps, so thread static variables will naturally cause problems.

To work around this, you can either use [`AsyncLocal<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn906268(v=vs.110).aspx) (available in .NET 4.6), or (if you must) [`HttpContext.Current.Items`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.items(v=vs.110).aspx). Of those two, I would definitely recommend `AsyncLocal<T>` over `Items`, if it's available on your platform.

Comment: Can I ask you the reason why you recommend AsyncLocal over Items?

Comment: I recommend `AsyncLocal<T>` over `HttpContext.Current` because `HttpContext.Current` is considered a poor design and has been removed in ASP.NET Core.