# IdentityServer4 and ResourceOwnerPasswordValidator Dynamic ConnectionString

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core, identityserver4

So, IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator is supposed to replace IUserService. 
In the old version IdentityServer3 I could do the following:

```
factory.UserService = new Registration<IUserService>(typeof(MyIdentityUserService));
factory.Register(new Registration<IUserRepository>(userRepository));
```

which passes a custom userRepository object with the proper connection string.
Now in IdentityServer4 I need to Connect to the proper Portal database in order for ID4 to authenticate the user against the correct portal database.

If I could pass a parameter to the constructor of the ResourceOwnerPasswordValidator class like below , then this would be fine but this is not possible with ASP.NET CORE.

```
 public ResourceOwnerPasswordValidator(string MyConnString)
        {
            _connstring = MyConnString;
        }
```

This can't work because the ConfigurationService registers this class without the ability to pass values. This makes sense since this registration process begins before the pipeline is built.  How do I dynamically pass a connection string to the ResourceOwnerPasswordValidator class? I am trying to authenticate against the portal making the call. In ID3 I could do this by using the acr_value.

I am trying to get ID4 to authenticate as a MultiTenant Authentication Server.

Answer (score 0):

You could inject a service or a DTO into a `ResourceOwnerPasswordValidator` constructor:

```
public class ResourceOwnerPasswordValidator : IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator
{
    public ResourceOwnerPasswordValidator(IAuthRepository repository)
    {
    }
}
```

Hence it is possible to pass a service which returns your connection string.

By default, validator's implementation is [registered](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/81ee8f39cdb5de1c6d058a490b956256791bc23a/src/IdentityServer4/Configuration/DependencyInjection/BuilderExtensions/Additional.cs#L54) as `Transient` which means it will not be a singleton until it is resolved in a singleton (which is not a IdSrv4 case I guess).

If you need a `Scoped` connection string (i.e. per web request), register a scoped DTO with a factory method: `services.AddScoped<T>(() => )` or use `AsyncLocal<T>`. Check this thread to get more details:

[How to Per-Request caching in ASP.net core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44348310/how-to-per-request-caching-in-asp-net-core)